# Check that only one Excel column from a group has value

Tags: excel

Let's say I have three columns and two rows in Excel. The first row is the same for all three columns. How can I check (or enforce) that only one cell in the second row is filled (others must be empty) ?

Now let's assume that I have three such groups of columns (nine columns in total and three distinct header row values) and again, I want only one (or none) column per group to have value, others must be empty. That is a maximum of three values can appear in these nine columns - one per group of columns.

How can this be done easily or at least efficiently? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend embedding three **COUNTBLANK** functions into an **IF** function.

Example:

> =IF(AND(COUNTBLANK(A2:C2)=2,COUNTBLANK(E2:F2)=2,COUNTBLANK(G2:I2)=2),"One value per group","Other")

[image]

Comment: Thanks... I thought of this, but could it be modified for dynamic number of columns and dynamic number of columns within a group? E.g. single COUNTIF formula that counts non-blank cells for each group? But in single cell (I do not want to expand my sheet data for this, they are already pretty large.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

This will monitor entries in columns **A**, **B**, and **C** below row #1.  If more than one entry in a row, the last entry will be cleared.  Place the following code in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim N As Long

    If Target.Row > 1 And Target.Column < 4 Then
        With Application.WorksheetFunction
            N = Target.Row
            If .CountA(Range("A" & N & ":C" & N)) > 1 Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                    Target.Clear
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```